# How to subtract a column of days from a column of dates in Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

Given the following PySpark DataFrame

```py
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('2015-01-15', 10),
                                 ('2015-02-15', 5)],
                                 ('date_col', 'days_col'))
```

How can the days column be subtracted from the date column? In this example, the resulting column should be `['2015-01-05', '2015-02-10']`.

I looked into `pyspark.sql.functions.date_sub()`, but it requires a date column and a single day, i.e. `date_sub(df['date_col'], 10)`. Ideally, I'd prefer to do `date_sub(df['date_col'], df['days_col'])`.

I also tried creating a UDF:

```
from datetime import timedelta
def subtract_date(start_date, days_to_subtract):
    return start_date - timedelta(days_to_subtract)

subtract_date_udf = udf(subtract_date, DateType())
df.withColumn('subtracted_dates', subtract_date_udf(df['date_col'], df['days_col'])
```

This technically works, but I've read that stepping between Spark and Python can cause performance issues for large datasets. I can stick with this solution for now (no need to prematurely optimize), but my gut says there's just got to be a way to do this simple thing without using a Python UDF.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to solve this using `selectExpr`.

```
df.selectExpr('date_sub(date_col, day_col) as subtracted_dates')
```

If you want to append the column to the original DF, just add `*` to the expression

```
df.selectExpr('*', 'date_sub(date_col, day_col) as subtracted_dates')
```

Comment: If you don't mind typing SQL you can actually simplify this to `df.select(expr("date_sub({0}, {1})".format("date_col", "days_col")))` which makes it trivial to compose.

Answer (score 17):

Use **`expr`** function (if you have **`dynamic values`** from columns to substract):

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> df.withColumn('substracted_dates',expr("date_sub(date_col,days_col)"))
```

Use **withColumn** function(if you have **`literal values`** to substract):

```
>>> df.withColumn('substracted_dates',date_sub('date_col',<int_literal_value>))
```

Comment: Hi Shu, I don't think that works because [date_sub](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.date_sub) takes one column and an integer value as parameters. It only works with [expr](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.expr) like: `df=df.withColumn('substracted_dates', F.expr('date_sub(date_col, day_col)')`.

Answer (score 2):

Not the most elegant solution ever but if you don't want to hack SQL expressions in Scala (not that it should be hard, but these are private to `sql`) something like this should do the trick:

```
from pyspark.sql import Column

def date_sub_(c1: Column, c2: Column) -> Column:
    return ((c1.cast("timestamp").cast("long") - 60 * 60 * 24 * c2)
        .cast("timestamp").cast("date"))
```

For Python 2.x just drop type annotations.

Comment: Clever. I think I found a slightly more elegant solution using `selectExpr`, but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

slightly different format, but also works:

```
df.registerTempTable("dfTbl")

newdf = spark.sql("""
                     SELECT *, date_sub(d.date_col, d.day_col) AS DateSub 
                     FROM dfTbl d
                   """)
```