# How to use date (as string) in structured query?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can i programmatically subtract days from a date in spark sql?

```
val date = "2019-10-01"

val tmp = spark.sql(""" 
select id, 
count(distinct purchase_id) as count_purchases
from
my_table
where partition_date between ('$date'-6) and '$date'
group by 1
""")
```

tried:

```
val tmp = spark.sql(""" 
select id, 
count(distinct purchase_id) as count_purchases
from
my_table
where partition_date between CAST(CAST('$date' as DATE) - interval '6' day) as varchar) and '$date'
group by 1
""")
```

receives the error:
`parser exception at varchar`

Also tried

```
val tmp = spark.sql(""" 
select id, 
count(distinct purchase_id) as count_purchases
from
my_table
where partition_date between sub_date('$date',6) and 
'$date'
group by 1
""")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with pure scala:

```scala
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val someDateStr = "2020-01-20 00:00:00"
val endDate = LocalDateTime.parse(someDateStr, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
val startDate = endDate.minusDays(6)

startDate
```

This will print `startDate: java.time.LocalDateTime = 2020-01-14T00:00` then you can use `startDate` and `endDate` in your query with string interpolation:

```
val tmp = s"""select id, count(distinct purchase_id) as count_purchases 
          from my_table 
          where partition_date between 
CAST('${startDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))}' AS DATE) and 
CAST('${endDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))}' AS DATE) 
          group by 1"""
```

Alternatively you can use the build-in [function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#date_sub) `date_sub` together with `CAST`:

```scala
val endDate = "2020-01-20"

val query = s"""select id, count(distinct purchase_id) as count_purchases 
          from my_table 
          where partition_date between date_sub(CAST('$endDate' AS DATE), 6) and CAST('$endDate' AS DATE)
          group by 1"""

spark.sql(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something I'd consider an more idiomatic Spark code would look as follows:

```
val date = "2019-10-01"
val q = spark.range(1).select(date_format(lit(date), "yyyy-MM-dd") as "end_date")
scala> q.show
+----------+
|  end_date|
+----------+
|2019-10-01|
+----------+
```

With that, and `date_add` SQL function, you can use this in a SQL query:

```
val q = sql("""
  select date_add(date_format('2019-10-01', "yyyy-MM-dd"), -6) as start_date
  """)
scala> q.show
+----------+
|start_date|
+----------+
|2019-09-25|
+----------+
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051299/how-to-subtract-a-column-of-days-from-a-column-of-dates-in-pyspark) answer.

> Use expr function (if you have dynamic values from columns to
>   substract):
>
> > > > from pyspark.sql.functions import *
> > > >         df.withColumn('substracted_dates',expr("date_sub(date_col,days_col)"))
> > > >         Use withColumn function(if you have literal values to substract):
> > > >
> > > > df.withColumn('substracted_dates',date_sub('date_col',))

Comment: adding `where partition_date between date_sub('$date',6) and 'date'` returns an empty dataframe

Comment: Please post code with pre-defined data so that we could reproduce the issue ourselves.

Comment: Please also define data. Use `spark.createDataframe`